# show if $\{u, v\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $a$ and $b$ are nonzero, then both $\{u+v,au\}$ and $\{au,bv\}$ are bases for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

i think my proof is correct but i'm not sure. it begins on the next line. $u$ and $v$ are distinct vectors.

$\{u,v\}$ is a basis, so:

$a_1u+a_2v=0, a_1=a_2=0$ by definition

consider the linear combination of $\{u+v,au\}$. let $c \in F$.

$c(u+v)+au=0$

$cu+cv+au=0$

$(c+a)u+cv=0$

by above linear combination for $\{u,v\}$, $c+a=a_1=c=a_2=0$, so $\{u+v,au\}$ must be linearly independent. and by properties of $\{u,v\}$, $\{u+v,au\}$ must also be generating. therefore this set is a basis for $V$.

consider linear combination of $\{au,bv\}$. let $p,q \in F$.

$p(au)+q(bv)=0$

$(pa)u+(qb)v=0$

by the linear combination for $\{u,v\}$, the linear combination of $\{au,bv\}$ is equivalent, which implies $pa=a_1=qb=a_2=0$, so $\{au,bv\}$ must be linearly independent. it also must be a generating set by the characteristics of $\{u,v\}$. therefore $\{au,bv\}$ is also a basis.

Comment: No, it isn't. You are missing a factor $d$, i.e. $$c(u+v)+d(au)=0.$$ Notice that if $a\neq 0$, your equation $$(a+c)u+cv=0$$ has no solution.

Comment: Other than that, it's correct.